# JNI ERROR (2354): JNI connection is NULL when I use JDBC to connect TDengine

Tags: java, database, jdbc, time-series

I'm working on a project to use JDBC from Windows to connect to the TDengine database running on Linux.

The config are set as following:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:TAOS://192.168.2.58:6030/test?timezone=UTC-8&charset=UTF-8&locale=en_US.UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=taosdata
```

I also investigated the log of TDengine.

```
06/29 18:29:30.630000 00018224 TSC starting to initialize TAOS client ...
06/29 18:29:30.630000 00018224 TSC Local End Point is:DESKTOP-PEO5CFV:6030
06/29 18:29:30.630000 00018224 UTL tsc scheduler is initialized, numOfThreads:6
06/29 18:29:30.630000 00018224 TMR ttimer monotonic clock source:POSIX clock_gettime
06/29 18:29:30.630000 00018224 UTL tmr scheduler is initialized, numOfThreads:1
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 TSC TableMeta:0000016FE156BF40
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 TSC client is initialized successfully
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL pool:0000016FE16D1CB0 is setup, maxId:5000
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 TMR ttimer monotonic clock source:POSIX clock_gettime
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL open udp socket:0x0:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL open udp socket:0x0:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL open udp socket:0x0:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL open udp socket:0x0:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00016360 RPC TSC UDP thread is created, index:1
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00004944 RPC TSC UDP thread is created, index:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL open udp socket:0x0:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00016308 RPC TSC UDP thread is created, index:2
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL open udp socket:0x0:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00011648 RPC TSC UDP thread is created, index:3
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 RPC TSC UDP connection is initialized, ip:0:0 threads:6
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 RPC TSC rpc is opened, threads:6 sessions:5000
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00008320 RPC TSC UDP thread is created, index:4
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 UTL cache:rpcObj, key:00000017E0BFA2A0, 0000016FE14D6C50 added into cache, added:1624962570631, expire:1624962575631, totalNum:1 totalSize:617bytes size:520bytes
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 TSC 0000016FE1A401E0 new SqlObj from 0000016FE19F3950, total in tscObj:1, total:1
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 TSC 0000016FE1A401E0 SQL cmd:connect will be processed, name:, type:0
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00000868 RPC TSC UDP thread is created, index:5
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 client connection is allocated, uid:0xe3df2b5e
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 RPC TSC UDP connection is setup, ip:6cdf6527:6030 localPort:63914
06/29 18:29:30.631000 00018224 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, connect is sent to 39.101.223.108:6030, len:377 sig:0x01000000:0x00000000:26895
06/29 18:29:31.636000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, expected connect-rsp is not received
06/29 18:29:31.636000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, re-send msg:connect to 39.101.223.108:6030
06/29 18:29:31.636000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, connect is sent to 39.101.223.108:6030, len:377 sig:0x01000000:0x00000000:26895
06/29 18:29:32.641000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, expected connect-rsp is not received
06/29 18:29:32.641000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, re-send msg:connect to 39.101.223.108:6030
06/29 18:29:32.641000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, connect is sent to 39.101.223.108:6030, len:377 sig:0x01000000:0x00000000:26895
06/29 18:29:33.646000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, expected connect-rsp is not received
06/29 18:29:33.646000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, re-send msg:connect to 39.101.223.108:6030
06/29 18:29:33.646000 00019936 RPC TSC 0000016FE3DE81B8 0000000000000002, connect is sent to 39.101.223.108:6030, len:377 sig:0x01000000:0x00000000:26895
```

I have no clue what's happening. Could someone give a hint on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception normally is caused by network configuration,client timezone doesn't match with the server client.
Try to use the taos client to connect with the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your JDBC connection string, use host name instead of IP address:

```
jdbc:TAOS://DESKTOP-PEO5CFV:6030/test?timezone=UTC-8&charset=UTF-8&locale=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly likely caused by the inconsistency between client and server versions. It looks to me that TDengine doesn't support backward compatibility. You have to make sure that the client version (i.e., libtaos.so downloaded in your java.library.path, e.g., /usr/lib) matches exactly the server version.

I tried with client version 2.0.22.0. It doesn't work with server 2.2 or 2.4. I have to downgrade the server back to 2.0.22.0.

If you run TDengine with docker, you'd better use specific tag instead of the default 'latest' in your image, e.g., tdengine/tdengine:2.0.22.0.

Comment: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:TAOS://192.168.2.58:6030/test?timezone=UTC-8&charset=UTF-8&locale=en_US.UTF-8`

You have to use hostname instead of IP in connection URL too.